# Create api request with more params/fields in Playwright

Tags: playwright

I have a problem with api request in playwright. I need to do this request to get a token. I have my old framework in cypress, and in cypress it looks like:

> export const get token = (
> userLogin,
> userPassword = 'userpassword,
> username = 'userID',
> password = 'secret',
> ) =>
> cy    .request({
> method: 'POST',
> url: 'xxx/oauth/token',
> auth: { username, password },
> form: true,
> body: {
> grant_type: 'password',
> username: userLogin,
> password: userPassword,
> },
> headers: { accept: 'application/json' },
> })
>
> And this is work. In playwriht i try do some like this:
> const responseToken = await request.post("xxxx/oauth/token",{
> data: {
> headers: { accept: 'application/json' },
> form: true,
> auth: { username, password },
> body: {
> grant_type: 'password',
> username: userLogin,
> password: userPassword,
> }
> }})

But I have problems with communications, request doesnt work.

In playwright i try do some like this:

> const responseToken = await request.post("xxxx/oauth/token",{
> data: {
> headers: { accept: 'application/json' },
> form: true,
> auth: { username, password },
> body: {
> grant_type: 'password',
> username: userLogin,
> password: userPassword,
> }
> }})

But I have problems with communications, request doesnt work (406 code)

I tried

> const responseToken = await request.post("xxxx/oauth/token",{
> headers: { accept: 'application/json' },
> form: true,
> auth: { username, password },
> data: {
> grant_type: 'password',
> username: userLogin,
> password: userPassword,
> }
> })
> but vscode told that arguments of this type is not assignable to parameter of type

Comment: Please format your code.